# Populating a vue formulate drop down with data from remote server

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-formulate

I have this formulate select component

```
<FormulateInput
      v-model="room_name"
      name="room_name"
      input-class="form-control"
      :options="getRoomNames()"
      type="select"
      placeholder="Select an option"
      label="Room Name"
      />
```

I am trying to get the populate the drop down with data from the database

```
getRoomNames (event) {
      var room_textfile = 'https://api.example.com/room_types/'+this.room_type + '.php';
  
  axios.get(room_textfile)
            .then(response => {    
                console.log(response.data);
                var rarr = response.data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
                console.log(rarr)
                return "{one:'One Star',two:'Two Stars',three:'Three Stars',4:'Four Stars',5:'Five Stars'}";
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });     
    }
```

The array i am getting is

```
0: "Budget Double or Twin Room"
1: "Cabin on Boat"
2: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room"
3: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Balcony"
4: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with City View"
5: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Garden View"
6: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Lake View"
7: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Mountain View"
8: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Ocean View"
9: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Pool Access"
10: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Pool View"
11: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with River View"
12: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Sea View"
13: "Deluxe Double or Twin Room with Spa Bath"
14: "Double or Twin Room"
15: "Double or Twin Room - Disability Access"
```

Before switching to formulate i was getting the data this way

```
getRoomNames (event) {
      var room_textfile = 'https://api.example.com/room_types/'+this.room_types + '.php';
  
  axios.get(room_textfile)
            .then(response => {    
                console.log(response.data);
                this.single_rooms = response.data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });     
    },
```

and showing it this way

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="room_name">
<option v-for="room_option_name in single_rooms" :value="room_option_name.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, '_')">{{room_option_name}}</option>
</select>
```

How can i migrate this to vue formulate?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRoomNames()` is currently returning `undefined`.

Just like you were doing earlier, set the response data to local state inside the success callback:

```
this.single_rooms = response.data;
```

Now you can pass this to the `options` prop:

```
<FormulateInput
  v-model="room_name"
  name="room_name"
  input-class="form-control"
  :options="single_rooms" /* <--- here */
  type="select"
  placeholder="Select an option"
  label="Room Name"
  />
```

The two way binding should populate the options when the data is retrieved

Comment: Ok. How do i make single_rooms here :options="single_rooms" show the label and value,should like loop through it some way?

Comment: @Gandalf, you don't need to do the looping, the library will do the looping for you

Comment: Ok fine, it does i have seen, but the value has spaces and i dont want spaces in my value ``<option value="Budget Twin Room">Budget Twin Room</option>`` the code looks like so

Comment: @Gandalf to get different value than the text label your items should be in the form of `{key: value}`, for eg: `{"btr": "Budget Twin Room"}` you can do this conversion in your backend or in frontend inside the success callback whichever is easier for you

Comment: Okay thanks, is hall do that in the backend,although i am curious how i would do that on formulate on client side for times that i need to set a current value without doing a trip to the server.

Comment: Didn't quite understand your question, the conversion of your array clientside would be something like `const converted = data.map(line => {
const value = line.split(' ').join(); return {[value] : line}; })`

Comment: Something wrong with your conversion, both the key and value are blank.

Comment: @Gandalf change to `.join('')` apparently default is `,`

Comment: That displays the value but i now cannot display the data on formulate.

Comment: I have this but removes space for key and replaces with underscore but now even the value has the underscore https://jsfiddle.net/w6rjhgu0/

Comment: That looks like it creates a single object rather than an array of objects. Please create a vuejs codesandbox

Comment: Should be something like const `value = val.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, '_');
    o[value] = val;` you’re modifying the original string